# Why are clients connecting so slow?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcpclient

I am trying to make a program in witch multiply clients will connect to the server. But i have a problem because when i try to connect more than 1 client at the same time, it takes a "long time" to do it.
i am using asynchronous way to connect:

```cs
 public bool connect(string IP,int port)                                                                                                       
    { 

        try                                                                                                                                       
        {

            if (m_clientSocket == null)
            {                                                                                                      
                m_clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);                                                                                                    
                IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(IP.ToString());
                int iPortNo = System.Convert.ToInt16(port.ToString());

                IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ip, iPortNo);                                                                                                      
                client.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
            }

        }catch()                                                                                                                
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            return false;                                                                                                                         
        }
    } 


private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            if (m_clientSocket != null)
            {
                if (m_clientSocket.Connected)
                {
                    client.EndConnect(ar);
                    // send next data here

                }
                else
                {
                    client.EndConnect(ar);
                    m_clientSocket.Close();
                    m_clientSocket = null;
                    state = CONNECT_ERROR; 
                }
            }

        }
        catch ()
        {   
        }
    }
```

For each client I want to connect I open a new class that includes two methods that you can see above. than with simple for loop I call methods one after another.

in Wireshark I observe the time that next needs to connect to a server is 0.1s witch I think is allot.

Any idea why does it take so long ?

Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: You're asking if 100ms is too long to connect to your server? If it's local.. yes.. if it isn't, then no.

Comment: 100 ms is not the time to connect to server but just time the my program needs start next client to start to connect

Comment: I don't understand why you do like you do. Why don't you initiate several connection attempts at the same time? And we also want to see the server accept code.